# Split character is not recognized

Tags: java, sockets, websocket, split

As I looked for a reliable character for splitting strings, I found out an earlier post about using "((char)007)" as a split character so i decided to use that for a request/response project I'm building.

But when I send data with "((char)007)" between data parts that need to be seperated, the data arrives at the other end of the socket like this instead "teq□weq□1231□21231".

So splitting this data properly is unsuccessful at the moment. Any ideas about why this happens and what kind of approach I might follow to fix this, what else I can use for splitting, any ideas would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Does your server read the request in the proper charset? What symbol you expect to be there? If it's `|` than it's `(char)124`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are printing control characters (BELL) then your console may not print it out properly.

In any case, consider just sending a structure like a serialized object (be careful with deserializing user-supplied content) or perhaps JSON. Any structure with a standardized format will do better in the long term versus arbitrary splitting on a magic character